# What is _Nullable pointer in C?

Tags: c

What does _Nullable mean in following declaration?

```
void foo(int *_Nullable ptr)
```

gcc of version 11.4 doesn't compile that code, because it treats _Nullable keyword as an argument name. Yet I see this keyword in man 7 pages:
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/epoll_ctl.2.html
https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timer_gettime.2.html

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:5,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:5,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:5,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:5),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Avoid+foo(int+*_Nullable+n)+%7B%7D%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++return+0%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g114,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O0%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+11.4+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between nullable, \_\_nullable and \_Nullable in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32452889/difference-between-nullable-nullable-and-nullable-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`_Nullable` simply means that the pointer passed to the function is allowed to be `NULL`. It is however not a keyword in C (and doesn't occur even once in the draft for the C23 standard) but an extension supported only by some compilers, for example [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) and [icx](/questions/tagged/icx).

The Linux `man` pages uses `_Nullable` to indicate to the readers that they are allowed to pass in a `NULL` pointer, but the actual declarations in the header files are free from `_Nullable`.

---

Libraries who wishes to give the compiler the static analysis and optimizing hints `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull` (indicating that the pointer may *not* be `NULL`) will optionally declare pointers as `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull` depending on which platform/compiler that is used.

Example: In `zipconf.h` (a platform specific include file for `libzip`) on Linux, you would see

```
#define _Nullable
#define _Nonnull
```

and all the `zip` functions *will* have both `_Nullable` and `_Nonnull` in their declarations. On Linux these will however be replaced with nothing thanks to the above `#define`s. On a platform dominated by [clang](/questions/tagged/clang) or [icx](/questions/tagged/icx) these definitions will not exist and the implementation specific keywords will then be passed on to the compiler as-is.

Answer (score 1):

The `_Nullable` and thus the `Nonnull` are hints for the programmer and the compiler tool for this variables. This allows some assumptions for the code like that checking for `NULL` is needed or not.
Interesting this gets when you have Objective-C code and you bridge it to Swift. In that case the IDE (or the underlying compiler AI) generates different data types which leads to differnet and clearer code.
I guess in some other languages it is the same.

So using this keywords is a good idea.

Tip: use some macro to redefine the value when your compiler doesnt support that feature for now.